How to use facet on Mongo aggregation
I am able to execute mongo query on mongo compass with below aggregation but I am not able to execute and get same result on Spring boot application
[
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          channelId: {
            $in: [1001],
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      operationTypes: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$operationType",
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            operationType: "$_id",
            count: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      states: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$state",
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            state: "$_id",
            count: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      results: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$result",
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            result: "$_id",
            count: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
]




I have tried to create list of AggregationOperation and then call as below and it didn't work
public List<AggregationResultTest> getAggregation(Aggregation aggregation) {
        AggregationResults<AggregationResultTest> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,COLLECTION_NAME,
                AggregationResultTest.class);
        return results.getMappedResults();
    }

I have tried to use Mongo Compass EXPORT TO LANGAUGE but it also didn't work. Here is what EXPORT TO LANGUAGE button returns
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.bson.Document;

Arrays.asList(new Document("$match", 
    new Document("channelId", 1001L)), 
    new Document("$facet", 
    new Document("operationTypes", Arrays.asList(new Document("$group", 
                new Document("_id", "$operationType")
                        .append("count", 
                new Document("$sum", 1L))), 
                new Document("$project", 
                new Document("_id", 0L)
                        .append("operationType", "$_id")
                        .append("count", 1L))))
            .append("states", Arrays.asList(new Document("$group", 
                new Document("_id", "$state")
                        .append("count", 
                new Document("$sum", 1L))), 
                new Document("$project", 
                new Document("_id", 0L)
                        .append("state", "$_id")
                        .append("count", 1L))))
            .append("results", Arrays.asList(new Document("$group", 
                new Document("_id", "$result")
                        .append("count", 
                new Document("$sum", 1L))), 
                new Document("$project", 
                new Document("_id", 0L)
                        .append("result", "$_id")
                        .append("count", 1L))))))

I could find a single example on mongo docs 4.4 but I couldn't understand very well. Can someone help me how can I implement that aggregation on Spring boot application?
IMPORTANT: Repository must be as below
@Repository
public class OperationHistoryRepository {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    // Aggrigation method should be in here
}

The problem still exists

With Spring Data MongoDB and MongoTemplate API, an example (shows usage and syntax) using aggregation facet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681366/delete-duplicates-items-based-on-condition/59720577#59720577

@prasad_ I am not able to use the way that you mentioned. I have a Cannot resolve method 'as' in 'Aggregation' compile error. Also, what you have mentioned is for Mongo 3.4. I don't know what is wrong with Mongo 4.4 but it doesn't accept the same format

The code was compatible with MongoDB v3.4, as that was the requirement. Specifically, it has some aggregation operators which were available with v 3.4.
